# Odoo POS showing incorrect Time (date_order)

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale

in Odoo v15, when I create a sale order, it's created for example with time 09:00.
When I open it in POS to settle it.
In the Sale Order Management Screen, the time in date appears 08:00, not 09:00.
But when I settle it and the pos.order record is created, I got 09:00 as a time in date_order.

How can I correct the 08:00 in the POS and show the correct time.
Please note that the correct time for me is 09:00.

Screenshots to clarify the issue:
[image: Origin Sale Order]

[image: POS]

[image: POS Order after settlement]

Thank you in advance.